# How to dynamically set a data-target id?

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I have three div's with different IDs. I would like to concatenate `myModal + i` into the `data-target` attribute, but I am unsure of how to do it. Here is my code:

```
success: function (response) {
    var work;
    var res = response.split("§");
    var modalid;
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length - 1; i++) {
        modalid = "myModal" + i;
        work = res[i].split("^");
        document.getElementById('eventi').innerHTML += "Cena del: " + work[0] + "<button type=\"button\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#\"\">leggi di piu</button>" + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('description' + (i)).innerHTML = work[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as you are already concatenating strings in the rest of your code, with `"...." + "...."`. Are you asking how to put `modalid` after the hash in data-target?

Comment: yes i want to know  that

Comment: I already try to do it with a simple concatenation but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With ES5 String concatenation

I've changed the wrapping quotes to single quotes to prevent the need to escape internal quotes.

```
document.getElementById('eventi').innerHTML +=
  'Cena del: ' + work[0] + '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#' + modalid + '">leggi di piu</button><br>';
```